# OpenCV addweight does not draw an overlay

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to overlay a transparent red rectangle box on top of an image and return the whole thing from a function.  For this, I'm using `cv2.addWeight()`.  I have a previous PIL rectangle function call that draws a rectangle outline to mark where the output should go in case it doesn't appear.  However, nothing is drawn unfortunately.  This is my output when I use the overlay function:

[image]

This is my code:

```
def overlay(path, lg_x, lg_y):
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    overlay = cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (lg_x, lg_y), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

    result = cv2.addWeighted(img, 1, overlay, 0.5, 1)

    pil_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(result))

    return pil_image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have to say that I didn't manage to reproduce the same error as yours using your function. There must be another problem somewhere. I had another error: a fully filled rectangle.

There is a problem in your code that does that:

`overlay = cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (lg_x, lg_y), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)` is also adding a rectangle over `img` therefore no matter what weights you put in `cv2.addWeighted`, your image will be full.

Here is a code that worked for me:

```
def overlay(path, lg_x, lg_y):
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    overlay = cv2.rectangle(img.copy(), (0, 0), (lg_x, lg_y), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

    alpha = 0.2
    output = cv2.addWeighted(img, 1-alpha, overlay, alpha, 0)

    output = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8(output), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(output)

    return pil_image
```

I used `cv2.rectangle` on a copy of the image, and changed the way you applicate the weights so that the total is always `1.0` (Here we have 20% opacity for the rectangle).
The `Image.fromarray` somehow made my colors wrong, I guess there must be another problem but since it wasn't the main problem, I didn't check deeper.

Comment: In my code, I'm pasting it on a background like this: `text_img.paste(new_logo, (logo_position_x, logo_position_y), mask=new_logo)`

Comment: `new_logo` is what `def overlay(...)` returns

Comment: You should try to isolate the error step by step. First, look at what ```overlay``` return by showing the image and checking, then do the next instruction, show the image... Once you find out which line cause the problem, don't hesitate to come back: it will be hard to help you without knowing clearly the problem (I don't know much about CV2, I only checked to help you on this ^^).

Comment: Figured it out. THe error is because I am converting it back to PIL.

Comment: However, I have to convert it to PIL because otherwise I will not be able to run the rest of the code..

Comment: I edited my answer and added PIL conversion with working colors. The transparent rectangle works fine for me.

Comment: `ValueError: bad transparency mask`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the problem, or create a new topic, as I shouldn't answer like this in the comments. However, I don't think you really understood what was a mask. Try to just remove the ```mask=new_logo``` and see if it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.5, overlay, 0.5, 0)
```